# No match for operator+ in C++ while using accumulate

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, accumulate

I am trying to calculate the average of the entries, but for some reason I am getting an unexpected error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘double’ and ‘const OrderBookEntry’)
  __init = __init + *__first;" 
              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

I am new to C++ and tried to solve this for a while, but nothing worked.

```
int MerkelBot::predictMarketPrice()
{
    int prediction = 0;
    for (std::string const& p : orderBook.getKnownProducts())
    {
        std::cout << "Product: " << p << std::endl;
        std::vector<OrderBookEntry> entries = orderBook.getOrders(OrderBookType::ask, 
                                                                p, currentTime);

    double sum = accumulate(entries.cbegin(), entries.cend(), 0.0);
    prediction =  sum / entries.size();
    std::cout << "Price Prediction is: " << prediction << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34fUo.png)

Comment: How do you "add" two `OrderBookEntry` objects? Perhaps you should use the overload of [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) where you provide a predicate which does the "adding"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are asking the compiler to add `OrderBookEntry` objects but the compiler doesn't know how to do that.

You have to tell the compiler what you mean by adding `OrderBookEntry` objects. One way to do that is to overload `operator+`

```
double operator+(double total, const OrderBookEntry& x)
{
    // your code here that adds x to total
}
```

But probably a better way would be to forget about `std::accumulate` and just write a for loop to do the addition.

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (auto const& e : entries)
    sum += e.something(); // your code here
```

with `something` replaced by whatever it is that you are trying to add up.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you don't want to add the book entries but the prices of the books. You can pass a function to `std::accumulate`:

```
double sum = std::accumulate(entries.cbegin(), entries.cend(), 0.0, [](double sum, const OrderBookEntry &bookEntry) {
    return sum + bookEntry.price;
});
```